# What is the right way to use the useCallback hook?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have an custom input component, like so:

```
import React, { useState, useCallback } from 'react'

function MyCustomInput ({value: initialValue = '0'}) {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(initialValue)

  const handleChange = useCallback(
    value => {
     setValue(value)
    },
    [setValue]
  )

  return (
    <SomeInputComponent onChange={handleChange}/>
  )
}
```

The useCallback implementation in React [doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback) says:

```
const memoizedCallback = useCallback(
  () => {
    doSomething(a, b);
  },
  [a, b]
)
```

Now as per the doc implementation, the correct way should be:

```
const handleChange = useCallback(
   value => {
     setValue(value)
   },
   [value] // And not, [setValue]
 )
```

But this would make the use of `useCallback` worthless as `handleChange` would start to get a new func reference each time the `value` state updates which would lead to unnecessary rerender of my `<SomeInputComponent>` component. Is my implementation incorrect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should include everything that is needed to create the function, the `value` is passed as a normal parameter when the function is called.

The only dependency needed to build the function in this case is `setValue`:

```
const handleChange = useCallback(
  value => {
    setValue(value)
  }, [setValue]
)
```

However, since `setState`, `dispatch` (from `useReducer`), and `useRef` are known to be static, you can omit them from the list of dependencies. The [exhaustive-deps rule](https://github.com/facebook/react/tree/f99fca3cb28e1fbd87e0b647ac43959add290be7/packages/eslint-plugin-react-hooks) has a function [`isDefinitelyStaticDependency(reference)`](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/f99fca3cb28e1fbd87e0b647ac43959add290be7/packages/eslint-plugin-react-hooks/src/ExhaustiveDeps.js) that looks for and "approves" this functions as static. So your code should be:

```
const handleChange = useCallback(
  value => {
    setValue(value)
  }, []
)
```

Comment: I'm assuming you mean `setValue` and not `setState`. But, can the setValue be skipped as well as the linter doesn't warn against it. Also, it doesn't make sense to pass even the setValue?

Comment: The linter should have warned about `setValue` because if it changes the function is regenerated.

Comment: Well, it did not. Even in the doc example, they are not passing `doSomething` as a dependency if you see. :/

Comment: @PaoloBiavati - The comment would have been enough to express your ideas. Adding a DV for an answer that acutally answers the question, because you don't agree with the original question is a bit aggressive.

Comment: @OriDrori I delete the previous comment (if may seem aggressive), but I still maintain that should not be used useCallback here.  
The right question could be "Should I have to use useCallback here?"

Comment: @PaoloBiavati - The comment was fine. That's your opinion. The DV was redundant. The answer answers the question.

Answer (score -2):

In your specific example the right way to use useCallback hook, **is NOT to use it**:

[the note in the doc](https://react.dev/reference/react/useCallback) is clear: *You should only rely on useCallback as a performance optimization. If your code doesn’t work without it, find the underlying problem and fix it first. Then you may add useCallback back.*

Your component no need it, handleChange only set the value state...

What kind of optimization are you doing? calling setValue need this optimization?